# Cannot seed data in the production database using heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using heroku to deploy my rails app. I am trying to seed some data in the production by running the command `heroku run rake db:seed`. However, the command is not working. I am not able to seed files in production. The `seeds.rb` file is given below.

```
# This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
# The data can then be loaded with the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).
#
# Examples:
#
#   cities = City.create([{ name: 'Chicago' }, { name: 'Copenhagen' }])
#   Mayor.create(name: 'Emanuel', city: cities.first)

# end


    5.times do              
    Scoreboard.create!(name_of_scoreboard: "scoreboard_abc",
                      name_of_organization: "abcdef",
                      name_of_activity: "ghijklmn",
                      user_id: 1,
                      states: "state",
                      country: "state",
                      cities: "state")
    end
```

I get the following message in the terminal when I run the command.

```
 $ heroku run rake db:seed
    Running rake db:seed on ⬢ app... up, run.4751
      ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

I run `heroku restart` but the objects isn't seeded in the production database. I have tried seeding this file in development and it works perfectly. I am not sure what's wrong. 

running heroku run rake db:setup gives me the following error

DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'

I also get the following errors.
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:955: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:963: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "mailboxer_conversations" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:971: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "mailboxer_notifications" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:979: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "mailboxer_receipts" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:987: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "managers" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:995: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "pg_search_documents" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1003: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "pictures" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1011: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "requests" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1027: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "scoreboards" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1035: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "statuses" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1043: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "team_matches" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1051: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "team_members" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1059: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "teams" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1067: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "topics" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1075: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "users" are not allowed
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1082: ERROR:  relation "index_categories_on_scoreboard_id" already exists
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1089: ERROR:  relation "index_documents_on_category_id" already exists
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1096: ERROR:  relation "index_events_on_scoreboard_id" already exists
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1103: ERROR:  relation "index_favourites_on_scoreboard_id" already exists
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1110: ERROR:  relation "index_favourites_on_user_id" already exists
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1117: ERROR:  relation "index_favourites_on_user_id_and_scoreboard_id" already exists
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:1124: ERROR:  relation "index_invitations_on_scoreboard_
```

I think I am running the migration files that already exist. As a result, I am getting a uniqueness error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have migrations pending.  You can try:

```
Heroku run rake db:migrate db:seed
```

Comment: I ran heroku pg:reset DATABASE, heroku run rake db:migrate and heroku db:seed in order. The migration shouldn't have been pending because I ran heroku run rake db:migrate. I tried your command but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps,

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Comment: schema.rb file doesn't exist for me. I have it changed to structure.sql because I am using tsvector columns for postgresql full text search. The first command doesn't work because the file doesn't exist. I tried it and I got the following error. /app/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rake db:migrate` to create it.

Comment: Can you try execute heroku run rake db:setup and then run heroku run rake db:seed